# Adding an additional vector to a vectors space $U$, prove $U=span(v,u_{1},\ldots u_{n})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm posed with the following statement to prove:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and define $U=span(u_{1},\ldots,u_{n})$, where for each $i=i,\ldots,n$, where $u_{i} \in V$. Now suppose $v \in U$. Prove $U=span(v,u_{1},\ldots,u_{n})$

My initial thought is to prove this by cases. One case where $U=span(u_{1},\ldots,u_{n})$ is linearly independent, and also when $U$ is linearly dependent.

If $U$ is the latter, I should be able use the linear dependence lemma.
However, I'm unsure how to go about it if $U$ is linearly independent, aside from considering that $a_{i}\otimes v=0$.

A tiny push is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $v\in U$ so $v$ is already a linear combination of the $u_i$s. Consider a linear combination of the $u_i$s and $v$. Expand $v$ and gather up the terms.

Comment: Do you know that $w_1, \dotsc, w_k \in U$ implies that $\text{span}(w_1, \dotsc, w_k)$ is a linear subspace of $U$?